# Loop count not what expected

Tags: java, loops, graphics

Currently trying to manage a game loop to a steady 60 frames. I followed the example I saw to a T, yet not getting expected output. Starting to wonder if my computer is just slow.

I use the following code to manage the number of renders per loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    int fps = 60;   //Number of renders wanted per second
    double timePerTick = 1000000000/fps;    //Alotted nanoseconds given desired fps
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); 
    int ticks = 0; //To track the number of times render() is called in 1 second

    while(isRunning) {

        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime)/timePerTick; //Delta here is very small #. Represents amount of the timePerTick used after looping through one time.
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;


        if(delta >= 1) {//This dictates whether a render occurs or not.
            render();
            ticks++;
            delta = 0;
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000) {//Prints out how many renders occurred in one second
            System.out.println("FR at " + ticks);
            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

In the example I followed, this code generated 60 frames consistently per printout. Mine is consistently printing out 23, 24, 17, 20, etc. No matter how I changed the `if(delta >= 1)` to something like `if(delta >= .0000001)`, it still prints out around the same number of renders/frames per second.

Obviously with a lower threshold, more renders should happen... but that is *not* happening. So at this point, I am extremely confused. I know I could use `Thread.sleep()` for this, but its not guaranteed to be accurate.

I'm not sure if y'all will want to see my render() method, but here it is:

```
private void render() {
    strategy = myCanvas.getBufferStrategy();

    if(strategy == null) {
        myCanvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }


    do {
        do {

            g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

            BufferedImage myImage = ImageLoader.getImage(path);//Do this in an instantiation method


            g.drawImage(myImage.getSubimage(0, 0, 110, 125), x, 0, 300, 300, null);

            strategy.show();
            x++;

        }while(strategy.contentsRestored());

        g.dispose();

    }while(strategy.contentsLost());

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *`BufferedImage myImage = ImageLoader.getImage(path);//Do this in an instantiation method` Umm.. pay attention to your own comments! Trying to load the image every time the loop is called is likely the cause of the slow-down! General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks Andrew, i'll check that out & do that in my future questions :)

Comment: Cool. In that case I might pay close attention to, and try to actually **answer** future questions. Of course, you can [edit] this question any time you like, and then I could withdraw the close vote & see if I can spot the error.  *"Any help is greatly appreciated!"* You've already seen the maximum amount of effort I'm willing to invest in this, short of improvements to the question. (You're welcome, BTW.)

Comment: Ah good idea haha. I will go about fixing this sucker up following what you posted above.